# Simple Kendo DropDownList binding in window

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a form with a DropDownList inside a Kendo window and I want to bind existing data to it. Examples for this abound and I've done it in other situations before, but this one (which seems like it should be really easy) is escaping me because I can't seem for the life of me to get the DropDownList to show the correct value. I figure I must be missing something really simple, but I haven't done Kendo in over a year, and looking at my previous work isn't helping me either.

Extremely simplified code:

```
<button onclick="OnButtonClick();">Click Me</button>

<div id="form-window"></div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="form-template">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Url">URL</label>
    <input name="Url" type="text" value="#= Url #" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="HttpVerb">HTTP verb</label>
    <input name="HttpVerb" data-bind="value:HttpVerb" data-source="httpVerbsDataSource" data-value-field="verb" data-text-field="verb" data-role="dropdownlist" />
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var formWindow = $("#form-window")
    .kendoWindow({
        title: "Form",
        modal: true,
        visible: false,
        resizable: false,
        scrollable: false,
        width: 500,
        actions: ["Close"],
        open: function () {
            kendo.init($("#form-window"));
        }
    }).data("kendoWindow");
  var formTemplate = kendo.template($("#form-template").html());

  var httpVerbsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { verb: "GET" },
        { verb: "POST" },
        { verb: "PUT" }
    ]
  });

  function OnButtonClick(e) {
    var dataItem = {
        Url: "abcdef",
        HttpVerb: "POST"
    };

    var windowContent = formTemplate(dataItem);
    formWindow.content(windowContent);
    formWindow.center().open();
  }
</script>
```

When I click the button, the window opens and the form text field is populated correctly, and the DropDownList has properly been bound to the data source, but the value in my data item is not selected.

JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/wariyorilo/edit?html,js,output

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was not able to find what is wrong with data-bind neither, but if you bind value directly to input's value, it binds correctly. I know it is not exactly solution you was looking for (with data-bind), but it could help you too. I would say that data-bind provides you functionallity, that if user changes value, it changes also in your model but it's not intended for setting default value (as it seems now) https://jsbin.com/vorelumaqe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Ademar Thanks for checking. The hack I came up with was to just manually set the value after opening the window, but I like yours better.